# Where exactly does the series of functions $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 (x+1)}$ converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

For $x \in (-\infty; -2]\cup [0;+\infty): \frac{1}{n^2 (x+1)}\le \frac{1}{n^2} $, so it conv. uniformly on $(-\infty; -2]\cup [0;+\infty)$ by the Weierstrass M-Test.
The problem is what happens when $x\in (-2;0)$? I tried using Cauchy criterion and choosing $x = -1 +\frac1{n^2} $, so that $|\sum_{k = m+1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^2 (x+1)}|\ge \epsilon$ for some given $\epsilon > 0$. But this can only show that the series is not uniformly convergent on the entire $(-2;0)$. What about any subinterval of it? Does it not converge on any subinterval? And how to prove it?

Comment: For any $\delta>0$, the function $\frac{1}{1+x}$ is bounded on $(-1-\delta,-1+\delta)^c$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$ (actually equals $\pi^2/6$) hence the series converges uniformly here by Weierstrass.

Comment: The problem is highly artificial as the expression is of the form $f(x)\sum a_n$. The series is uniformly convergent on any  interval $I$ where $f(x)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac 1 {n^{2}(x+1)}$ does not tend to $0$ uniformly in any open interval containing or touching $-1$. (To see this take $x=-1\pm \frac  1 {n^{3}}$). So the series does not converge uniformly in any such interval, but it converges uniformly in any interval that stays away from $-1$ (by M-test)

Comment: You mean take $x = -1 +\frac{1}{n^3}$ and apply Cauchy criterion?

Comment: @Sgg8 A necessary condition for uniform convergence of $\sum f_n(x)$ on a set $S$ is $f_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly on $S$. Here this condition is not satisfied for any set that contains $-1$ as a limit point.  So 'staying away from $-1$' is N & S for uniform convergence